# Save email as draft in php

Tags: php, email, imap, uid

The past few days I've been trying to find out how I can save emails as drafts using php. I've created an emailaddress that uses imap (and resides on the same server).

What I would like to do is to use php to create an email and store it in the drafts folder. These emails would then be recognized by the email client (ms office outlook in this case) so they can be editted and send from the email client.

I've found some interesting information about the imap functions from php, they let you send mail, but I can't really figure out how to store them in the drafts folder (to which I have write access). I can actually find and read the emails, I save as drafts in my email client, using my ftp connection. However they make use of UID and message-ID's and such which I don't understand where they come from.

My questions:
- how could I create email drafts
- How does a new UID or message-ID get created, and how would I use them for my email-draft file?

Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Yorian

Comment: There's a possible Duplicate that should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206275/creating-messages-ie-drafts-in-gmail-with-imap-smtp

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked if the proper extension is installed? To use the php imap functions the php5-imap extension must installed. You can check this by using `phpinfo()`. When there stands nothing about "imap", the extension is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [imap_setflag_full](http://php.net/manual/function.imap-setflag-full.php). there's a \draft flag.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can use imap_append() to store the mail in the INBOX.Draft mailbox ([function.imap_append](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php))