# Way to delay SMTP pickup outgoing mail

Tags: email, delphi, smtp, iis-6, delphi-xe8

I am working on an application (in Delphi XE8) that amongst other things allows the user to send emails. The solution I have chosen is to simply save the email as a text file with a "From:" and "To:" field in a SMTP pickup directory, which has worked fine up to now. I use a SMTP virtual server set up in IIS 6.

However, a new requirement is to be able to choose the sending time of the email. Is there some way I can specify this through the text file, or is this only possibly by changing the IIS settings? I would be very grateful for any tips that anyone may have.

Comment: afaik IIS is not a mail server. Are you using Exchange?

Comment: Hi @mjn, no, I'm not using Exchange. I set up a SMTP virtual server using IIS on my server machine. Sorry for being unclear, I'll edit my question.

Comment: I don't think such feature exists in IIS6. You might want to save the files to other directory and make a dedicated pickup service move them to the SMTP pickup directory based on your timing. your time info could be a header in that text file which your pickup service will remove before moving it to the SMTP pickup directory.

Comment: @kobik, yes, that could also be an alternative. I'll look into it, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using IMAP4 (standard protocol for service-based handling of mails and folders for a mail client) instead of SMTP. Then use an email client that supports postponing of sending messages, and use its scripting to configure message sending the way you want it.

If your program continues running till send time, you could also create a thread that waits till the time you want the message sent, but I suppose that is too simple :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This seems a bit precarious, since the application will be installed on a client's computer and while they are happy to set up a SMTP pickup folder for me, they are not likely to change their email routines just for this application. I think I will have to go with the threading approach! But thanks for the hint, I'll have to learn a bit more about IMAP4!

Comment: the mail client doesn't have to be hosted locally, it can be a web-based one like gmail too. See this thread for a coding example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461085/delphi-indy-saving-gmail-draft

Comment: Thank you @Jur for you time and the excellent example! I will definitely look into your suggestions more.

Comment: IMAP is not designed for sending emails. It is a protocol to access items in mail box. He should use SMTP to send the email.

Answer (score 1):

If your code can detect the From And To fields correctly, why not just add a Time: entry in your text file and skip that file if the time has not been reached?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I guess I could store the intended emails in sending order and through a separate thread 'release' them when their time arrives...I was hoping there was a slightly more convenient way to do it though.